# Lucene query syntax

Tags: lucene

I want to write a Lucene query which is the equivalent of the following SQL

```
where age = 25
and name in ("tom", "dick", "harry")
```

The best I've come up with so far is:

```
(age:25 name:tom) OR
(age:25 name:dick) OR
(age:25 name:harry)
```

Is there a more succinct way to write this?

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
age:25 AND name:(tom OR dick OR harry)
```

alternatively

```
+age:25 +name:(tom OR dick OR harry)
```

Answer (score 4):

Does this work?

```
age:25 AND (name:tom OR name:dick OR name:harry)
```

I understand this may not be what you're looking for. I didn't know if the purpose of your question was to factor out the `age:25` clause or if it was to eliminate the `name:` prefixes.

If you make `name` your `QueryParser`'s default field, you could reduce this down to:

```
age:25 AND (tom OR dick OR harry)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not much more succinct, but you can try:

```
(age:25) AND (name:tom OR name:dick OR name:harry)
```